# javascript:S2583 false positive

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I think I found a false positive:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
for (const item of items) {
  if(item) { //Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false".
    ....
  }
}
```

> Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false".

I do not understand why it creates this ticket. I could understand if it would say that it alway evaluate to "true" as `document.querySelectorAll` should not return `null` results.

Any ideas?

We are using the 2.13 version of the javascript plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.14 does not raise an issue on this kind of code.